# How to change individual values in a CSV using Python

Tags: python, csv, filereader

Here I have a CSV file:

```
123456789,Football,100,19
123456789,TennisRacket,120,35
```

Using Python, how can I change the number  35 (the quantity of a tennis racket) on the second line by -1 each time the user wants to buy one? Here is my code:

```
areyousure = input("Are you sure you want to purchase? Y/N")
    areyousure = areyousure.upper()
if areyousure == "Y":
    itemfile = open("Bought items.text","w")
```

What can I put under this code that decreases the number 35 by 1 every time the user types "Y"?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to read the csv into an array, edit, and then write a new csv.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a try:

```
import csv    

areyousure = input("Are you sure you want to purchase? Y/N")
    areyousure = areyousure.upper()
if areyousure == "Y":
    itemfile = open("Bought items.text","w")

    # Create a Python array from your csv
    with open('/yourCSVfile.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        r = list(reader)

    r[1][3] -= 1 # access 35 in the new array, subtract 1

    # Overwrite your csv with the modified Python array
    with open("yourCSVfile.csv", "wb") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(r)
```

That wouldn't be great you call it often (in a loop for instance).

Comment: Thanks, will try it soon!